# 2D array null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays

Okay, first off I can guarantee this has been asked, but I haven't found my specific problem and I don't have the rep to comment on an existing post. Basically I've instantiated a 2D array as a class object, since I need to access the array in multiple methods and changes have to stay permanent. However I don't know the actual needed size needed to create the matrix, and am getting null pointer exceptions when I try to change the size later.

Basically:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Character> line, int row)
{
    System.out.println("line size " + (line.size()-1));
    System.out.println("maze row check " + (maze[row] == null));
    maze[row] = new int[line.size()-1];
    for (int x = 0; x <line.size(); x++)
    {
        maze[row][x] = line.get(x);
        System.out.println("final sopt " + maze[row][x]);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to successfully do this? Or am I overlooking something very simple? 
Thank you for taking the time to read / answer this,
Mark

And after what must be 10 edits going in circles here is the full code (full of printlns from testing and other code i just commented out because I didn't need it or wrote something better:

```
package maze;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Maze
{
private static int[][] maze;

public Maze(int size, String line)
{



}

public boolean hasExitPath(int r, int c)
{
    return false;
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    return output;
}

public static void doMaze(int x, int y)
{

}

public static void readMaze() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println(0);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("maze.dat"));
    String numString;
    int numLine;
    String mazeLine;
    int row = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int lastChar = 0;

    while ((numString = read.readLine()) !=null && (mazeLine = read.readLine()) !=null)
    {
        System.out.println(1);
        numLine = Integer.parseInt(numString.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
        System.out.println("numString" + numString + "numLine" + numLine); //both set to 5...
        ArrayList<Character> curLine = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int d = 0; d < numLine; d++) curLine.add('a');
        System.out.println("curLine " + curLine.size());

        for (int z = 0; z < mazeLine.length(); z++)
        {
            System.out.println(2);
            // get first row of numbers >> need to check lastchar
            // sort and send to get added
            // if remainder of line is more than numLine
                // go to step one, but start from lastchar
            if (lastChar < curLine.size())
            {
                System.out.println(3);
                for (x = 0; x < numLine; x++);
                {
                    System.out.println(4);
                    curLine.add(mazeLine.charAt(x + lastChar));
                }
                lastChar = x + lastChar;
                System.out.println("row " + row);
                sort(curLine, row);
                row++;

            }
            else{System.out.println("error"); System.out.println(lastChar); System.out.println(curLine.size());}

        }
        /*
        numLine = Integer.parseInt(numString.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
        ArrayList<Character> curLine = new ArrayList<Character>(numLine);
        for (int x = 0; x < numLine; x++)
        {
            //System.out.println(mazeLine.charAt(x));
            System.out.println(maze[0][0]);
            curLine.add(mazeLine.charAt(x));
        }
        y++; */ 
    }
    read.close();
}

public static void sort(ArrayList<Character> line, int row)
{
    System.out.println("line size " + (line.size()-1));
    System.out.println("maze row check " + (maze[row] == null));
    maze[row] = new int[line.size()-1];
    for (int x = 0; x <line.size(); x++)
    {
        maze[row][x] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(line.get(x)));
        System.out.println("final sopt " + maze[row][x]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post a complete example that we can actually compile.

Comment: `maze[row][x] = new int[someArrayList.size() -1];` will never compile.

Comment: method 5(ArrayList x, int row) followed by previous comment does not make sense

Comment: Do you ever initialize `maze`?

Comment: okay, well I can already see one of my issues, the arraylist contains Char values because I am reading from a dat file, and I'm using an int type list, so I need to fix that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time consider posting a [MCVE]

Comment: You can't set `maze[row]` to be a `new int[something]` until you've set `maze` to a `new int[something][something]`.  Otherwise `maze[row]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks DM, I've already thought about that, but again, I don't know the actual size needed until I read from the dat file. So I need a way to either set the matrix as a class object and still have the right dimentions (they change so I can't see how I could do this), or somehow change the length of the list. Could I create a matrix from ArrayLists?